# Apple IPad 16gb

Tags: itunes

I have all the necessary information like password and email address but I am unable to remove the apple account / icloud / iTunes accounts from my new device. How can I get them removed so I can add my information to my device.

Answer (score 1):

According the blog [OSXDAILY](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/01/change-apple-id-ios/) these are the steps to remove the the informations from the iPad:

Open the Settings app in iOS and head to “iTunes & App Store”
Tap on the “Apple ID: email@address.com” text at the very top of the Store screen.
At the Apple ID management pop-up window, tap on “Sign Out”